# Галерея с изображениями разными по ширине

Tags: javascript, html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Как реализовать галерею с изображениями, разными по ширине, но фиксированными по высоте?

Необходимо, чтобы изображения сами распределялись и ужимались в зависимости от места в блоке *div*. Есть скрипт *masonry*, но там, как я понял, такая штука работает только по вертикали.

Как примерно должно выглядеть, показано на рисунке:

[image: пример]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно подключить плагин который автоматически будет выводить фото Например:

[Демо 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...](http://collageplus.edlea.com/example.html)

Там сверху есть ссылка ( CollagePlus jQuery Plugin Example ) где можно скачать плагин.

Успехов.

Answer (score 5):

Фиксированная высота, под которую подгоняется картинка, и выравнивание по двум краям с пустотами между картинками?

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Comment: к чему это прописывать? к изображениям или к диву?

Comment: @dikardRus, контейнеру. Картинкам только высоту.

Comment: немного не то, нужен эффект как у масонри, только горизонтально. Наглядный пример раздел "Картинки" в google (если высота у изображений одинаковая) или фотоальбом в приложении ВК на андроиде.

Comment: Эм.. @dikardRus, ты хочешь не только выровнять элементы в контейнере, но и переупорядочить их таким образом, чтобы расстояния были минимальны?

Comment: ну да, типо того

Comment: Но зачем же писать код, когда можно просто подключить плагин, ага? )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не понял.

Comment: @Qwertiy: это я иронизирую над конкурирующим ответом, на котором больше плюсов и галочка.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, на том ответе правильно галочка. У меня только обеспечение выравнивания. Отображение в нужном порядке флексбоксу тоже просто прописать, но вот по поводу вычисления, в каком порядке надо располагать элементы, чтобы они красиво влезли, у меня ничего нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy: а, ну ладно, понял ) Но всё равно такие решения меня немного огорчают. На apple.se так вообще на половину вопросов предлагают купить приложение, которое это делает.